# ping with absolute time stamp

Tags: linux, ping

is it possible to put the system time in front of the ping for every ping packets?

for instance, when I ping 1000 times per second, we see something like this:

```
# ping 9.0.0.150 -i 0.001
PING 9.0.0.150 (9.0.0.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.531 ms
64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.473 ms
64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.497 ms
```

what I want is something like this:

```
# ping 9.0.0.150 -i 0.001
PING 9.0.0.150 (9.0.0.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
12345123.122122 64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.531 ms
12345123.123122 64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.473 ms
12345123.124122 64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
12345123.125122 64 bytes from 9.0.0.150: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.497 ms
```

where the numbers in the prefix is system time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
ping 9.0.0.150 -i 0.001 | while read line
do
   echo $(cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/uptime) $line
done
```